# Converting user input of Nested lists into a nested list

Tags: python, string, list, user-input

So I'm writing a program to print out nested lists into a flat list, and I am just trying to get the input part now. I am having trouble because inputting the shown array would give me a string and using list() has put all of the elements including the brackets/commas into a list as well.

```
arr = input("Enter your nested array here: " )
#arr = ast.literal_eval(list(arr)) just something I tried here
#arr = [[[1,2,3], [4,5]], 6]
flatArr = flattenArrays(arr)
print (flatArr)
```

Is there a good way for me to convert this commandline input or a file input into a list of lists?

Comment: Did you try just `ast.literal_eval(arr)`?

Comment: `eval` is evil, but it looks exactly like what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `list` call, that converts your string to a list of characters - something you *don't want*.

```
In [14]: x = ast.literal_eval(input('List: '))
List: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 6]

In [15]: x
Out[15]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 6]

In [16]: type(x)
Out[16]: list
```

Comment: Ok that worked I swear I tried it before but I have no idea what I did differently that made it not work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @HanC If it worked, smash that accept button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use `json` method `loads`:

```
import json
a = '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 6]'
a = json.loads(a)
a
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 6]
```

Comment: Note that it _requires_ OP to ensure data is entered in JSON format (matters with strings), or else this is going to fail.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Noted :)

Comment: yea I tried this too before and it didn't work! probably because of what coldspeed said